# style属性のみを使い、一定のウィンドウ幅を超えたら2段組みになるようにしたい

Tags: html, css

いつもお世話になります。
css埋め込みのみによる回りこみ制御を考えています。

横幅780px以上の場合、

```
<div style="float: left; width: 50%;">a</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 50%;">b</div>
```

とし、横幅がこれを下回る場合、

```
<div style="float: left; width: 100%;">a</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 100%;">b</div>
```

以上のようなことをmax-width,min-width等の埋め込みのみで制御したいのですが、
何かいい方法はありませんでしょうか？

こちらではこんな感じで作ってみましたがイマイチです。

```
<div style="float: left; width: 390px; max-width: 100%; height: 200px; background: black;" ></div>
<div style="float: right; width: 390px; max-width: 100%; height: 200px; background: yellow;"></div>
<div style="float: left; width: 390px; max-width: 100%; height: 200px; background: red;" ></div>
<div style="float: right; width: 390px; max-width: 100%; height: 200px; background: gray;"></div>
```

基本的に実現したいことは、親要素の横幅780px以上の場合、子要素を２列で表示し、
親要素の横幅780px未満になる場合は子要素を１列で表示したいです。

埋め込みだけでもできそうな感じはするのですが、
皆さんのお知恵をお借りしたいと思います。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 埋め込みというのは `<style>` タグも使えないのでしょうか？（タイトルにはstyle属性のみと書いてしまいましたが）

Comment: 個々の“要素”のタグに style属性としてスタイル情報を埋め込むだけで実現したいです。<style>タグは使えません。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 親要素のstyle属性は変更出来るのでしょうか。

Comment: 親要素への変更はできません。ただし自分自信が親になり以下に子を複数作れます。ですので親子の相互関係を作ることは可能です。よろしくお願い致します。やはり無理っぽいでしょうか・・・。

Answer (score 1):

`display: flex`の要素を作り、段組みしたい要素をその子要素にするというのはどうでしょうか。
両方の子要素に`flex: 1 1 390px`と指定すると、`390px`(とりあえず 780/2 で適当に決めました)をベースとして必要に応じて同じ比率で伸縮するようになります。
親要素に`flex-wrap: wrap`としているので、ベースの`390px`が保てない幅になったら自動で折り返され縦組になります([Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes))。

```css
/* 本題と関係ないスタイルはこちらに集めています */
div{
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 background-color: lightblue;
}
#parent{
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent"><!-- 変更出来ない親要素 -->
                                                                  
 <div style="width: 100%; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap">
  <div style="flex: 1 1 390px">
   A
  </div>
  <div style="flex: 1 1 390px">
   B
  </div>
 </div>
                                                                  
</div>
```

---

本題とずれますが:
「親子の相互関係を作ることは可能」な状況でしたら、そこに`style`タグを挿入してしまう事も出来そうですがいかがでしょうか。
昔のHTMLは`style`タグは`head`内に書かないといけないという仕様でした（現実の実装では無視しても動いたようですが）。
現在のHTML5では`scoped`属性を付ければ仕様に違反せず挿入出来ます。

Comment: 脱帽、まさしくこれです。Flexboxとは恐れ入りました。styleタグが使えないのはあるポータルの投稿箇所にタグが使えて単純にstyleタグが禁止されているだけです。タグが使えても1行の縦組ではつまらんと思ったのがことの発端ですが、しかし、このFlexboxはかなり使えそうですね。リキッドレイアウトのコーディングが非常に楽になりそうです。ありがとうございました。